# Regex matching on a substring and returning the string between specific delimiters

Tags: ruby, regex, delimiter

Let's say I have a string that can be formatted a few different ways, for example:

- "languages:(ruby AND python) role:(software engineer or data
  scientist)"
- "role:(software engineer or data scientist) languages:(ruby AND python)"
- "languages:'python' role:'software engineer'"
- "languages:(ruby AND python)role:(software engineer or data
  scientist)"
- "languages:'python'role:'software engineer'"
- "languages:'python'

And I want to parse this string, identify if `role:` is present in the string and then capture whatever word(s) are relevant to "role", excluding whatever isn't wrapped in the close parans `)` OR the `'`... so in this example, `"languages:'python'role:'software engineer'"` would return "software engineer" and `"role:(software engineer or data scientist) languages:(ruby AND python)"` would return "software engineer or data scientist".

Is there a way to do this with something LIKE a word boundary? Specifically, the region after the match on `role:` would be delimited by either quotes or `()`?

Comment: Try `s.scan(/role:\(([^()]+)\)/)` or if you only expect 1 match per string, `s[/role:\(([^()]+)\)/, 1]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - this works well for the parens case, I'm trying to tweak your regex a little bit to cover the `"languages:'python' role:'software engineer'"` and `"languages:'python'role:'software engineer'"` case!

Comment: Or [`s.scan(/role:(?:\(\K[^()]+(?=\))|'\K[^']+(?='))/)`](https://regex101.com/r/uqEzWE/2)? [Demo in Ruby](https://ideone.com/AxUZU0).

Comment: That did it. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Want to add it as an answer so I can give you the credit for your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
s.scan(/role:(?:\(\K[^()]+(?=\))|'\K[^']+(?='))/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uqEzWE/2)

**Details**

- `role:` - a literal substring
- `(?:` - start of an alternation non-capturing group:

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `\K` - [*match reset operator*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discarding the text matched so far
  - `[^()]+` - 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `(?=\))` - a `)` should follow the current position
- `|` - or
- `'` - a `'` char
- `\K` -  match reset operator discarding the text matched so far
- `[^']+` - 1+ chars other than `'`
- `(?=')` - there must be `'` char immediately to the right
- `)` - end of the alternation group.

NOTE: if you do not care if there is a `)` or trailing `'`, remove the lookaheads to simplify the regex.

[Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/AxUZU0):

```
s  = "languages:(ruby AND python) role:(software engineer or data scientist) role:(software engineer or data scientist) languages:(ruby AND python) languages:'python' role:'software engineer'  languages:(ruby AND python)role:(software engineer or data scientist) languages:'python'role:'software engineer' languages:'python'"
puts s.scan(/role:(?:\(\K[^()]+(?=\))|'\K[^']+(?='))/)
```

Output:

```
software engineer or data scientist
software engineer or data scientist
software engineer
software engineer or data scientist
software engineer
```